# How can I get rid of old agricultural plastic?

Tags: plastic, agriculture

The previous owners of my land laid down AG plastic, which has deteriorated over the years. Unable to roll and every time I mow I cut into it and goes everywhere, including my neighbor's (it is on the fence line).

I am trying to find a solution that would be cost effective. Can someone give me advice as I am breeding sheep and not wanting them to eat the plastic while they are grazing.

Can I burn the plastic out of the ground?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing agricultural plastic film waste after 10+ years degradation](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/4665/3379)